# How do I fetch a resource from AWS S3 in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

The [AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html) is quite clear and straightforward:

```php
<?php

// Include the AWS SDK using the Composer autoloader.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

try {
    // Get the object
    $result = $s3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname
    ));

    // Display the object in the browser
    header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
    echo $result['Body'];
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

This strongly suggests that `$result['Body']` is the actual content of the file (in my case, a JSON document). However, if I do `print_r($result['Body'])` I get a Guzzle Object:

```
Guzzle\Http\EntityBody Object
(
    [contentEncoding:protected] => 
    [rewindFunction:protected] => 
    [stream:protected] => Resource id #9
    [size:protected] => 
    [cache:protected] => Array
        (
            [wrapper_type] => PHP
            [stream_type] => TEMP
            [mode] => w+b
            [unread_bytes] => 0
            [seekable] => 1
            [uri] => php://temp
            [is_local] => 1
            [is_readable] => 1
            [is_writable] => 1
        )

    [customData:protected] => Array
        (
            [default] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I retrieve the actual content of the file?

composer.json

```json
{
  "require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.9.3",
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel I'm missing something stupidly simple here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guzzle `EntityBody` classes can just be cast to a string to fetch the actual response, so in your case

```
$response = (string) $result['Body'];
```

For a bit of clarity — the reason the example works is that when calling `echo`, the following variable (or statement) is automatically cast to a string. When calling `print_r` instead, you get a more detailed view of the object, which may or may not include the string you're looking for.